# Properties with default values in Mongoose schema are not persisting

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following schema I've written using Mongoose:

```
var querySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    quoteId: { type: String, default: '' },
    zipcode: { type: String, default: '' },
    email: { type: String, default: '' },
    type: {type: String, default: ''},
    isEmailChecked: { type: Boolean, default: true },
});
```

I provide values for only 3 properties in the `querySchema` assuming that the result of the fields will take default values when a new instance of `query` object is persisted:

```
var query = {};
query.quoteId = "1414775421426";
query.email = "myself@somewhere.com";
query.type = "Foo";
```

But following document is what I see as the result in the collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5453c27d0e4c3f2837071856"),
    "email" : "myself@somewhere.com",
    "type" : "Foo",
    "quoteId" : "1414775421426",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Should `isEmailChecked` and `zipcode` not be assigned their default values when a new instance of `query` object is persisted to the MongoDB database?

Following is how I am persisting an instance of the query object using ExpressJS/NodeJS:

```
app.post('/api/queries', function (req, res) {
    QuoteQuery.create({
        quoteId: req.body.query.quoteId,
        type: req.body.query.type,
        zipcode: req.body.query.zipcode,
        email: req.body.query.email,
        isEmailChecked: req.body.query.isEmailChecked,
    }, function (err, query) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(query);
    });
});
```

Could somebody help me understand that why I got the `isEmailChecked` and `zipcode` properties in the resulting document in the MongoDB database?

I am using NodeJS, AngularJS and ExpressJS in my application along with MongoDB.

Answer (score 2):

When you set mongoose model field it not use default value.

As workaround you can use underscore to extend mongoose model object with keys which exists in your `query` object like this:

```
_.extend(dbQueryObject, query);
```

Here is complete example:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var querySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  quoteId: { type: String, default: '' },
  zipcode: { type: String, default: '' },
  email: { type: String, default: '' },
  type: {type: String, default: ''},
  isEmailChecked: { type: Boolean, default: true }
});

var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/stackoverflow',
  { server: { auto_reconnect: true } },
  function(err) {
    var QuerySchema = db.model('test', querySchema);

    var query = {};
    query.quoteId = "1414775421426";
    query.email = "myself@somewhere.com";
    query.type = "Foo";

    QuerySchema.create({
      quoteId: query.quoteId,
      type: query.type,
      zipcode: query.zipcode,
      email: query.email,
      isEmailChecked: query.isEmailChecked
    }, function (err, query) {
      process.exit(0);
    });
  });
```

Here is what in db:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5453ce3c9f7e0d13c52abf61"),
    "type" : "Foo",
    "email" : "myself@somewhere.com",
    "quoteId" : "1414775421426",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: But if I add `created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }` as another property in the `querySchema` and do not set it at the server end explicitly, it does store the default value as `Date.now` for the `created` property of the newly created `query` instance.

Comment: if you are running express locally if you change the schema please ensure this is restarted - for anyone else reviewing this question the above `{ type: Date, default: Date.now }` works as expected and  stores the default value.